# consulta sobre python y tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo este programa que tiene un cubo celeste que es arrastrable, cuando este se arrastra a la zona gris y se presiona el boton de "compilar",escribe codigo dentro de un archivo llamado "data.py" que hace que genere una ventana.

mi problema esta que si pones dos cubos de "crear Ventana" en la zona gris no va generar dos ventanas.

Realize varios intentos, uno fue hacer una variable que cuente la cantidad de cubos arrastrados, pero me escribe muchas lineas de codigo dentro de "data.py". tuve el mismo resultado si en vez de una variable lo hago dentro de una array.

puede ser que el programa tenga uno que otro problema,si me pueden ayudar en cualquier cosa estaré muy agradecido.

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk





#Creacion de ventana

window = Tk()
window.title  ('SLP: Simply Learn Programming')
window.geometry('1550x1250')
window.configure(bg='#1c1c1a')

#cubos generados
cb1list = []

#clase para que los cubos se arrastren

class cb1(Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.drag_startcb1)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.drag_motioncb1)
    

    def drag_startcb1(self,event):
        
        self.startX = event.x
        self.startY = event.y

    def drag_motioncb1(self,event):
        global x1,y1
        x1 = self.winfo_x() - self.startX + event.x
        y1 = self.winfo_y() - self.startY + event.y
        self.place(x=x1,y=y1)

#funcin para agregar un cubo

def add_labelcb1():
    global count_nuevocb
    global cubo1n
    count_nuevocb=count_nuevocb+1
    cubo1n = cb1(window, bg="cyan", width=15, height=3, text="Crear Ventana")
    cubo1n.place(x=15, y=50)
    cb1list.append(cubo1n)

boton_agregarcb1= Button(text="Nuevo Label",bg="#3d3d3b",fg="white", command=add_labelcb1)   
boton_agregarcb1.pack()
boton_agregarcb1.place(x=37, y=58)
count_nuevocb=0

#coordenadas

x1=0
y1=0

ZonaTrbj = Canvas(window,bg="#3d3d3b",width=800,height=900)
ZonaTrbj.place(x=270,y=0)

bordeizq = Label(window,bg="#3d3d3b",width=1,height=900)
bordeizq.place(x=270,y=2)

bordeder = Label(window,bg="#3d3d3b",width=1,height=900)
bordeder.place(x=1071,y=2)

cubo1 = cb1(window,bg="cyan",width=15,height=3,text="Crear Ventana")
cubo1.place(x=15,y=50)

def cords():
    for hacer_codigo in range(1250):
        if x1 >= 240 and x1<= 860 and hacer_codigo==y1:
             with open('data.py', 'w') as archv:
                archv.write("from tkinter import *\n")
                archv.write("from tkinter import ttk\n")
                archv.write("window = Tk()\n")
                archv.write("\n")
                archv.write("\n")
                archv.write("\n")
                archv.write("\n")
                archv.write("window.mainloop()\n")     
    
    subprocess.call(["python", "data.py"])

def restart():
    archv= open('data.py', 'w')
    cubo1.place(x=15,y=50)
    archv.write(" ")
#borra todos los cubos generados
    original_positions = [(50, 50)]  # Agrega aquí las ubicaciones originales de las etiquetas
    labels_to_delete = [label for label in cb1list if (label.winfo_x(), label.winfo_y()) not in original_positions]
    for label in labels_to_delete:
        cb1list.remove(label)
        label.destroy()

botonc = Button(text="Compilar ▶",bg="#3d3d3b", fg="white",command=cords)
botonc.place(x=530, y=0)

botonr = Button(text="Restart ↺",bg="#3d3d3b", fg="white",command=restart)
botonr.place(x=600, y=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cuando pueda, veré si puedo ayudar. Solo quería aclarar que no hablas de cubos, hablas de cuadrados. Los cubos son en 3d, los cuadrados son en 2d. Cada cara de un cubo es un cuadrado